# copying a lot of files from bucket to bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I’m trying to write a process to copy large amount of files from one bucket to another.

I started with google-cloud-python plain, it crashed at ~3k files with some 503 errors, then I moved to batch mode (still with python libs) and crashed at ~10k files because operations where taking more than the fixed 30 seconds time out, and then when I tried to use `blob.rewrite` found is not implemented on batch mode at python library.

Now I’m thinking of use `subprocess.run` to call `gsutil`, but as the files are arbitrary in the sense they don’t share a dir or mask. I’ll have to run the command for each file, and this could be super slow. I’m currently reading the documentation and can’t find a way pass a list to one gustil execution (like a json, cvs, etc).

Said that so, what would be the proper way of copying a lot of arbitrary files from one bucket to another?

Comment: It feels like this is the API you would want to use.  Executed it once per file that you want to copy from one bucket to another. - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/copy

Answer (score 0):

For a large number of file, I recommend you to set up a [file transfert](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-program) between 1 bucket to the another one.

Programmatically, it will take you a lot of time (to code and to transfert), you have to handle the retries in case of fail, the multi thread transfert and all this boring stuff. The transfert service do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, but as far I'm reading, file transfer doesn't allow arbitrary file lists in a an easy way. Only trough http, and I would have to create an gstorage access token for each file I want to transfer.

Comment: Ok, you didn't mention that you want to filter/process your file during the transfer. Can you describe what exactly you want to achieve in your question?

Comment: sure, I receive a large list of files from internal customer, which are located in one "sacred" bucket, and my app needs to copy those files to a "play ground" bucket where other people can mess around with those files.

Comment: Isn't easier to copy all the files from your sacred bucket with File Transfer and then to delete the useless file?